# Command line argument Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

I understand that a segmentation fault means I'm trying to use memory I shouldn't be touching, but I can't figure out where it's coming from in my code. I wrote a program for an assignment that uses vigenere's cipher to encipher some plain text. It compiles fine but when I run it with a command line argument I get a segmentation fault.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
// check to make sure the user entered a key
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("You need to enter a key, and only one. Please enter an alphabetical key. \nSyntax: ./vigenere key \n");
        exit (1);
    }

// check to make sure the key is alphabetical
    string k = argv[1];
    if(isalpha(k) == false)
    {
         printf("Pleas enter an alphabetical key.\n");
         exit (2);
    }   
// Get a string of plaintext
    printf("Please enter your secret messege.\n");
    string p = GetString();
// Encipher
    int lk = strlen(k);
    int lp = strlen(p);
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < lp; i++, j++)
    {
        if(isupper(k[j]))
        {
            tolower(k[j]);
        }
        if(j > lk)
        {
            j = 0;
        }
        if(isalpha(p[i]))
        {
            if (islower(p[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", ((((p[i] - 97) + (k[j] - 97)) %26) +97));
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", ((((p[i] - 65) + (k[j] - 97)) %26) +65));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", p[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just compile your program with debugging flags (e.g. `-g` if you use gcc) and run the program with a debugger (e.g. `gdb`). it will show you the line that is causing the segfault.

Comment: One of your arrays is probably going out of bounds, as Pavel said, use a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code looks suspicious:

```
if(isupper(k[j]))
    {
        tolower(k[j]);
    }
    if(j > lk)
    {
        j = 0;
    }
```

You use k[j] but the check afterwards suggests that j could be greater than lk. So k[j] could be out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Your line `if(isalpha(k) == false)` is not checking the entire string. isalpha() takes only an integer argument.

You will have to look the entire string and call isalpha() for every character.

```
for( size_t i = 0 ; i < strlen( k ) ; i++ )
{
    if(isalpha(k[i]) == false)
    {
        printf("Pleas enter an alphabetical key.\n");
        exit (2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was getting a segmentation fault when implementing isalpha() in this wrong way. Using the loop is what I needed. Same assignment too (cs50)!

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this code we need to know what is in cs50.h, how data type "string" is defined and what GetString() is.  It is possible the segmentation fault occurs at line: string p = GetString(); if p is a pointer and no memory is allocated to store the the "string" returned by GetString().

If cs50.h is not included, "string" is redefined as a character array, and GetString() is replaced by fgets() (along with a few other minor changes), the code works.  See below and adapt it as needed for your class.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // check to make sure the user entered a key
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("You need to enter a key, and only one. Please enter an alphabetical key. \nSyntax: ./vigenere key \n");
        exit (1);
    }

    // check to make sure the key is alphabetical
    //string k = argv[1];
    char *k = argv[1];
    char *sp;
    for (sp = argv[1]; *sp != '\0'; sp++) {
        if(!isalpha(*sp))
        {
            printf("Pleas enter an alphabetical key.\n");
            exit (2);
        }   
    }

    // Get a string of plaintext
    printf("Please enter your secret message.\n");
    //string p = GetString();
    char p[256];
    fgets(p, 256, stdin);

    // Encipher
    int lk = strlen(k);
    int lp = strlen(p);
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < lp; i++, j++)
    {
        if(isupper(k[j]))
        {
            k[j] = tolower(k[j]);
        }
        if(j > lk)
        {
            j = 0;
        }
        if(isalpha(p[i]))
        {
            if (islower(p[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", ((((p[i] - 97) + (k[j] - 97)) %26) +97));
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", ((((p[i] - 65) + (k[j] - 97)) %26) +65));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", p[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```